# Any way to tell if the user clicked on the last row in a datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Alright so you know the datagridview has a last line, where you are able input something?
Is there any way to tell if the user has selected this line?

I'm trying to program an application where you select a row in a datagridview. After selection, you may add click a button which removes the row from the datagridview (and an xml file)
Now I want the program to delete a row you've selected. But I'm currently using this method to update which row the user is selecting.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        rowNumber = e.RowIndex;
    }
```

[image]

Here's a picture of the GUI so you know what I'm talking about.
Den Sorte Liste means the black list, "Tilføj post" is the add-button, "Slet post" is the remove button.

Please come with questions if my explaination sucks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is if you are using data binding.

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem == null)
{
  //Last row
  ...
}
```

or use dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex instead of e.RowIndex
if you want to access it outside of an event handler.

Comment: I don't know exactly what data binding is but CurrentCell.RowIndex works perfectly.

Comment: Databinding helps to populate a control without manual interactions. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fbk67b6z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. There is a basic example about databinding and datagridview